# Combine alias functions

Tags: graphite

Using Graphite, I'm plotting some graph and the same with a time shift.

Eg:

```
aliasByNode(my.application.metric.$Continent.$DC.*, 4, 5, 3)
aliasByNode(timeShift(my.application.metric.$Continent.$DC.*, "7d"), 4, 5, 3)
```

But I'd like to be able to identify the graphs (they currently get the same name).

How to add a prefix or a suffix (or any marker) to a metric alias?

Eg:

```
-- EU.PAR.pokemonCaught
-- EU.PAR.pokemonCaught (last week)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use regex with [`aliasSub`](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.aliasSub)  to grab whole ( `(.*)` ) metric and change it - add desired text ( `\1 last week` ). E.g.

```
aliasByNode(timeShift(my.application.metric.$Continent.$DC.*, "7d"), 4, 5, 3)
```

should look like

```
aliasSub(aliasByNode(timeShift(my.application.metric.$Continent.$DC.*, "7d"), 4, 5, 3), "(.*)", "\1 last week")
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just use [alias()](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.alias) to rename it however you like.

Comment: I cannot, because I have several series (multiple $Continent and multiple $DC). So using a hard-coded alias would hide the Continent and the DC.

Comment: Sorry, brain fart on my part. I was initially going to suggest `aliasSub` but I thought that was overkill lol.